# php mysql result add html tags

Tags: php, mysql

Here is some php mysql query code. I want make some query with pagination. each page have 10 results.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE uid='132828' ORDER BY date LIMIT ".$number.",10 ");
$num = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   if($num ==1){
       echo '<ul class="left">';
   }
   if($num ==5){
       echo '<ul class="right">';
   }
   //what about these code here? 
   if($num%5==0){
       echo '</ul>';
   }
}
```

And I want out put the html like:

```
<ul class="left">
  <li> 1st result </li>
  <li> 3rd result </li>
  <li> 5th result </li>
  <li> 7th result </li>
  <li> 9th result </li>
</ul>
<ul class="right">
  <li> 2nd result </li>
  <li> 4rd result </li>
  <li> 6th result </li>
  <li> 8th result </li>
  <li> 10th result </li>
</ul>
```

So, how to add html tags in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you research this topic by any means? I mean pagination is out there for like forever, there are many tutorials to get you going.

Comment: @Boo, I am tring to make singular results wrap into `<ul class="left">
`, the others wrap into `<ul class="right">`

Answer (score 0):

you are not incrementing `$num`
try this

```
$num = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   if($num ==1){
       echo '<ul class="left">';
   }
   if($num ==5){
       echo '<ul class="right">';
   }
   //what about these code here? 
   if($num%5==0){
       echo '</ul>';
   }
   $num++ ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
$num = 1;
$ul_first= '<ul class="left">';
$ul_second= '<ul class="right">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   if(($num%2)==1){
       $ul_first.= '<li>'.$row['result'].'</li>';
   }
   if(($num%2)==0){
       $ul_second.='<li>'.$row['result'].'</li>';
   }

   if(($num%10)==0){
       $ul_first.= '</ul>';
       $ul_second.= '</ul>';
   }
   $num++ ;

}
echo $ul_first;
echo $ul_second;
```

Comment: @fish_man If you find my answer helpful and it solved your problem then please accept it. so it will help others