# Displaying db rows through <ul> with equal or less <li>

Tags: php, html

The following is a query results stored in $performset.

```
      $sqlperform = $ilance->db->query("
            SELECT
            q.title_per 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "perform q
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "perform_answers a ON (q.cid =  a.cid)
            WHERE a.user_id = '" . $res_vendor['user_id'] . "'
        ");
        if ($ilance->db->num_rows($sqlperform) > 0)
        {
            while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlperform))
            {  
            $perform .='<li>'.$rows['title_per'].'</li>';  
                }
                      $performset .='<ul>'.$perform.'</ul>';
         }      

  echo
```

The values i get from particular variable are
Adobe Flex, C++ Builder, C#/.Net, C/C++/Unix, C/C++/Win32SDK, Oracle DBA, 
Data Entry,

The out put I have got form this is

```
Adobe Flex, C++ Builder, C#/.Net, C/C++/Unix, C/C++/Win32SDK, Oracle DBA, 
Data Entry, Oracle DBA, Adobe Flex ,C++ Builder, C#/.Net , Data Entry
C/C++/Unix, C/C++/Win32SDK
```

But the output I need is

```
Data Entry    C++ Builder   C/C++/Win32SDK
Oracle DBA    C#/.Net
Adobe Flex    C/C++/Unix
```

The html that works for this is as such

```
    <ul>
                            <li>Data Entry</li>
                            <li>Oracle DBA</li>
                            <li>Adobe Flex</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>C++ Builder</li>
                            <li>C#/.Net</li>
                            <li>C/C++/Unix</li>
                        </ul>
```

How can i script it in php to produce such n number of results

Comment: it will may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599065/php-mysql-result-add-html-tags/9599548#9599548

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Foreach Loop not using break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686545/php-foreach-loop-not-using-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is perfect in this case.

Take a looks at this example, might looks complicated but might be how you need

```
    if ($ilance->db->num_rows($sqlperform) > 0)
    {
        $drows = array();

        while($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlperform)) {  
           $drows[] = $rows;
        }


        $chunks = array_chunk($drows, 3, true);       
        foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
          $set = "<ul>";
             foreach($chunk as $key => $value) {
                $set .= '<li>'.$value['title_per'].'</li>';  
             }
          $set .= "</ul>";
          echo $set;
        }

      }
```

#### TESTED, but For test, I used the following codes, which simulates the situation above

```
$ar1  = array(1,2,3); //db row
$ar2 = array($ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1,$ar1);

$drows = $ar2; //collection of db rows
$chunks = array_chunk($drows, 3, true);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
  $set = "<ul>";
     foreach($chunk as $key => $value) {
        $set .= '<li>'.$key.$value[0].'</li>';  
     }
  $set .= "</ul>";
  echo $set;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting on line 8 here

Comment: @Nabeel, How come? I tested it. Where is line 8? Is it Line 8 of my code?

Comment: foreach($chunk as $key => value) its at this line its showing , unexpected ')' don't know clearly... checking...

Comment: @Nabeel, Oh the `$` infront of value, I always seem to forget that. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: @Nabeel, that is because `$value['title_per']` is returning null. Try `var_dump($value)` and paste the output here

Comment: array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'C/C++/Win32SDK' (length=14)
      'title_spa' => string 'C/C++/Win32SDK' (length=14) this is output

Comment: You are receiving, multidimensional array as the output from $drows, travarse one step deep, like  `$value[0]['title_per']`

Comment: k now this value is printed C/C++/Win32SDK , but others are still missing

Comment: @Nabeel, I am sorry, but i will not be able to code every outcome for you.

Comment: It was helpful 4 me....But I just thought ,let others must not sit confused with this result..if had enough reputation i cud have edited it,but am still a child learning to swim here :) Thanks 4 ur kind heart bro...

Comment: @Nabeel, You can edit others answer too. But I will have confirm that to be shown that to others. Go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable that increments in the while loop, and if the variable is divisible by 3, you need to add `</ul><ul>`. Then just toss a `<ul>` before the loop and a `</ul>` after. Something roughly like this should work... (untested)

```
    if ($ilance->db->num_rows($sqlperform) > 0) {
      $i = 0;
      $performset = '<ul>';
      while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlperform)) {
        if ($i % 3) {
          $perform .= '</ul><ul>';
        }
        $perform .='<li>'.$rows['title_per'].'</li>';
        $i++;
      }
      $performset .='</ul>';
     }
```

Comment: hey in the endwhat should i echo.... if i echo $performset nothin will be shown..

Comment: its not entering the loop if($i%3) output now is <ul></ul>

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a counter to your while loop.
2. If the counter % 3 is 1, then `$performset .='<ul>'.$perform.'</ul>';`
3. In your template, `<ul> + $performset + </ul>`